# formula not calculating correctly

Tags: formula

I have a field, Requested Completion Date that needs to be calculated by adding the Length of SOW (Months) to the Requested Start Date and the date that it returns needs to be on a weekday. I have the below formula which works for the most part, but it does not ensure that it falls on a weekday and I'm not sure how to add that piece in here.

```
ADDMONTHS([Opportunity].Requested_Start_Date__c ,[Opportunity].Length_of_SOW_Months__c )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE` and `WEEKDAY` to achieve it.

```
CASE( WEEKDAY(ADDMONTHS([Opportunity].Requested_Start_Date__c ,[Opportunity].Length_of_SOW_Months__c )),
    1, ADDMONTHS([Opportunity].Requested_Start_Date__c ,[Opportunity].Length_of_SOW_Months__c )+1,
    7, ADDMONTHS([Opportunity].Requested_Start_Date__c ,[Opportunity].Length_of_SOW_Months__c )+2, 
    ADDMONTHS([Opportunity].Requested_Start_Date__c ,[Opportunity].Length_of_SOW_Months__c ) 
)
```

> WEEKDAY(date)
>   Return the day of the week for the given date, using 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, through 7 for Saturday.

Comment: I have forgotten about WEEKDAY() a couple of times now. They should update those help docs that tell you how to use MOD() to calculate it.

Comment: @salesforce-sas process builder says the formula is missing a ")", but it has all the correct opens and closes... any idea why/where so I can save and test?

Comment: Sry, forgot `ADDMONTHS` :/ . corrected in answer